# everytime i try to run my game it gives me 2 different errors

Tags: c#

i need help every time i try to play my game it comes up with two error messages Assets\BlinkScript.cs(60,24): error CS1002: ; expected
and Assets\BlinkScript.cs(46,94): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
i have no idea why and i really need help also im trying to make a blink script like how tracer and teleport a couple feet in over watch here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;  
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BlinkScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
    public int Uses;
    public float cooldown, Distance, speed, destinationMultiplier, cameraHeight;
    public text UItext;
    public transform cam;
    public layerMask layerMask;

    int maxUses;
    float cooldownTimer;
    bool blinking = false;
    vector3 destination;
    particleSystem trail;
}
    void Start()
    {
        trail = transform.find("Trail").GetComponent<particleSystem();
        maxUses = Uses;
        cooldownTimer = cooldown;
        UItext.text = uses.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
{
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            Blink();
        }

        if(Uses < maxUses);
    {
        if(cooldownTimer <0) cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime; 
        else {Uses += 1; cooldownTimer = cooldownl; UItext.text = Uses.ToString(); }
    }

    if (blinking)
    {
        var dist = vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination);
        if(dist > 0.5f)
        {
            transform.position = vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, Time = .deltaTime * speed);
        }
        else { blinking = false; }
    }


    void Blink()
    {
        if(Uses > 0);
    {
            Uses -= 1;
            UItext.text = Uses.ToString();
            trail.Play();

            Raycast hit
            if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out hit, distance, layerMask))
            
                destination = hit.point * destinationMultiplier;
                Debug.DrawLine(cam.position, hit.point * destinationMultiplier, Color.yellow, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                destination = (cam.position + cam.forward.normalized * distance) * destinationMultiplier;
                Debug.DrawRay(cam.position, (cam.forward * distance) * destinationMultiplier, Color.green, 2);
            }

            destination.y += cameraHeight;
            blinking = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate specifically which lines these errors refer to?  At a glance I at least can see that you have some semi-colons terminating some of your `if` blocks, which will produce behavior you don't expect.  And you also have a line that just says "Raycast hit" which isn't valid code at all.  Unless you meant to declare a variable called `hit` of type `Raycast`, in which case that's *probably* the line referred to by the first error.  Basically it looks like you just have a bunch of typos, and the error messages are pointing you to the ones which result in invalid syntax.

Comment: Extra semicolon here `if(Uses > 0);` and missing semicolon here `Raycast hit`. Incidentally, do you not need to have these functions inside a class, your `BlinkScript` closes its brace higher up?